# How To Use Groovy HTTPBuilder To Get Stories from AgileZen?

Tags: api, rest, groovy, integration, agile

I would like to pull stories from Agile Zen using their REST API.

I read:

- http://help.agilezen.com/kb/api/overview
- http://help.agilezen.com/kb/api/security

Also, I got this to work: http://groovy.codehaus.org/HTTP+Builder

How would one combine the above in order to get Groovy client code to access AgileZen stories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code sample which makes one story with id of 1 show up for a specific project whose id is 16854:

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.GET
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON

public class StoryGetter {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new StoryGetter().getStories()
 }

  void getStories() {
     // http://agilezen.com/project/16854/story/4
   // /api/v1/project/16854/story/2
  def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://agilezen.com' )
  http.request( GET, JSON ) {
    uri.path = '/api/v1/project/16854/story/1'
    headers.'X-Zen-ApiKey' = 'PUT YOUR OWN API KEY HERE'

    response.success = { resp, json ->
        println "json size is " + json.size()
        println json.toString()
    }
  }
 }
}
```

I had to put in a fake API key in this post since I should not share my API key.

(By the way, this is not using SSL. A follow up question in regards to doing this for a SSL enabled project may come soon.)

Comment: Helpful tip: uri.path = "/api/v1/project/${PROJECT_ID}/stories"  and json.totalItems gets you the total number of stories.   Renaming json to stories would be good to do too.